# Repeat Formula X Times

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a VB Script in Excel to populate a row of cells with a specific script but only one of those cells needs to increase by 1.

In Cell A2

```
=IF(Data!B37="","",Data!B37)
```

In Cell A3

```
=IF(Data!B38="","",Data!B38)
```

The rest of the cells on this tab are fixed formulas as long as something is in the A cell on that row.

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(Data!$B$5="","",Data!$B$5))
```

I can use the Record Macro and apply it to a button but is there a way to allow a user to choose how many times to repeat this code down?

In other words, I can record a macro keying in the cell by cell and I can apply that to a button. That's the easy part. I need to be able to allow the user to key in a number of rows needed like "10" in some cell and it repeats the script 10 times down starting on A2 thru I2 which counts for 1, then row 2 starting on A3 thru I3 counts for 2, etc. If not, I could deal with having them click the button 10 times if that makes it easier.

Ultimately, I'm trying to get around the Excel workbook printing the blank cells with formulas with no values. Currently, it says there are 70 pages for something that has 4 pages. I think this will help.

Much appreciated!

Update: (Figured out how to make a cell with a variable in VB Script)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

For c = 5 To 5

    For i = 2 To ActiveCell.Value
        For j = 1 To 2

            Worksheets(c).Cells(i, j).Value = 100
          Next j
    Next i
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to start with these, a loop (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) and an inputbox to capture how far to loop (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/inputbox-function.html). Then post a question to us if you get stuck with your code so far.

Comment: Sounds good. I will look into that right now.

Comment: @Zerk Oh snapples. I'm learning to destroy this VB SCRIPT! It will become my pet. In other words, so far I have figured out this so far. I can make a variable in a cell and make it loop that many times. Just a matter of using formulas and integrating this. 

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  

Dim c As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer  

For c = 5 To 5  
    
    For i = 2 To ActiveCell.Value  
        For j = 1 To 2  
           
            Worksheets(c).Cells(i, j).Value = 100  
          Next j  
    Next i  
Next c  

End Sub`

Comment: @Zerk One follow up question. I've thoroughly confused on adding formulas into VB Script. It wants to remove my quotations. I could create a cell with a formula and hide the sheet. But, I'd like to see about hiding the code in the script if possible. I read about R1C1 format and still scratching my head. I get confused because my cells are on different sheets too. Could you provide some insight on that roadblock and I may be able to soar to the finish line. So if I wanted to add something goofy like "=if(a1="","",a1), how could i get that to work?

Comment: If you want to use quotation marks for a formula in VBA you just double up the marks. That formula for example would be "=if(a1="""","""",a1)"

Comment: @Zerk *Face Palm* Thanks. That was easy. I'll keep tinkering with it and see what kind of monster I create.

Comment: @Zerk Go ahead and post an answer. I'll choose it as the best. If I have further questions, I'll ask the community later as I've done some VBA soul searching. I was excited about 7 years ago when I mastered the IF command. I have this same new excitement all over again. I really wanted the site you shared to be more in depth but I found homeandlearn.org. Now I'm able to read a lot of this code like a story. All I know is that I'm pretty good in just plain excel but wow was I missing out on a much better level. But anyhow, since I have a ton to learn, I'd rather ask a better question later.